# What is prevailing opinion among Jews at the current time regarding a future resurrection?

Tags: resurrection-of-the-dead, afterlife

Do most religious Jews expect a future resurrection the dead, general or specific, or not?

Comment: Haven't heard from you in a while, how's it going?

Comment: Fine; thanks for asking, Rabbi.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the traditional world holds by [Rambam's 13 principles of faith](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/332555/jewish/Maimonides-13-Principles-of-Faith.htm), the thirteenth of which is:

> The belief in the resurrection of the dead.